# There is any way to extend a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there any way to extend a dictionary in python?
I would like to have more than one value in one key.

```
a = { "abc" : "cbd" , "asd" , "asd"}
```

Comment: Keys in dictionaries have to be unique. To store multiple values against a key, you can use lists. Like so `a = {"abc": ["abc", "def"]}`

Comment: use `dict.update(dict)` operation

Comment: Do keep in mind that `update` will overwrite existing keys

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to have more then a one value in one key.

I think if you would like to have more than one value in one key it makes more sense having a list as value?

```
a = { "abc" :["cbd"] , "asd": ["asd"]}
print(a)
#adding new element
if a.get("abc",False): 
   a["abc"].append("new_item")
else:
   a["abc"] = ["new_item"]

print(a)
```

Would return something like

```
{'abc': ['cbd'], 'asd': ['asd']}
{'abc': ['cbd', 'new_item'], 'asd': ['asd']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
a = { "abc" : "cbd"}
a["abc"] = ["cbd", "asd", "fgh"]  # change the value of "abc" to be a list of your choice of values
```

In the list you put anything you want.

If you need the key's value for example "fgh"
you can do this:

```
a["abc"][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `list` as the value of the `dict` and append:

```
a = { "abc" : ['1']
a["abc"].append('2')
print(a)  # {'abc': ['1', '2']}
```

**EDIT:**

You can have the duplicate values in the `list` as well:

```
a = { 'abc' : ['cbd']}

a['abc'].append('asd')
a['abc'].append('asd')

print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'abc': ['cbd', 'asd', 'asd']}
```